# Get Dynamic Pivot Result into temp table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get dynamic pivot result into temp table by which I can send it back to C# code using select query.

```
DECLARE @partymasterid bigint = 2;
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT 
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '[' + CAST(dbo.InventoryProductMaster.Name AS nvarchar(max)) + '],' 
                   FROM dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster 
                   INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster ON dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.InventoryPartyProductPriceMasterID = dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster.ID 
                   INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryProductMaster ON dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster.InventoryProductMasterID = dbo.InventoryProductMaster.ID 
                   WHERE dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.PartyMasterID = @partymasterid 
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '');

SELECT @query = 
'
SELECT
*
FROM 
(SELECT
Count(dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.ID) AS BiltyCount,
--dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.InventoryProductMasterID,
--dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.VehicleMasterID,
dbo.InventoryProductMaster.Name,
dbo.VehicleMaster.VehicleNumber

FROM
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster
INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster ON dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.InventoryPartyProductPriceMasterID = dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryProductMaster ON dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster.InventoryProductMasterID = dbo.InventoryProductMaster.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.VehicleMaster ON dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.VehicleMasterID = dbo.VehicleMaster.ID
WHERE
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.PartyMasterID = ' + CAST(@partymasterid as nvarchar(50)) + '
GROUP BY
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.InventoryProductMasterID,
dbo.InventoryProductMaster.Name,
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.VehicleMasterID,
dbo.VehicleMaster.VehicleNumber
)
AS S
PIVOT
(
    MAX(BiltyCount)
    FOR [Name] IN (' + LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols)-1) + ')
)AS pvt';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Here may be result have 3 column or 5 columns or 10-15 columns. it depends on the result of query. and this result i want on temp table for use more this data.
I want to use it in a stored procedure to send back result into ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store inside a `#` (temp table) without defining it in the parent scope when using `sp_executesql`. In your case you have a dynamic `pivot` and you don't know what and how many columns are going to be there.

`sp_executesql` runs in a different session (sp_executesql creates its own session) and temp tables are session specific.

For your scenario you can use `##` (global temp table). You can change your query like following.

```
SELECT @query = 
'
SELECT
* into ##temp
FROM 
(SELECT
Count(dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.ID) AS BiltyCount,
--dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.InventoryProductMasterID,
--dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.VehicleMasterID,
dbo.InventoryProductMaster.Name,
dbo.VehicleMaster.VehicleNumber

FROM
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster
INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster ON dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.InventoryPartyProductPriceMasterID = dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryProductMaster ON dbo.InventoryPartyProductPriceMaster.InventoryProductMasterID = dbo.InventoryProductMaster.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.VehicleMaster ON dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.VehicleMasterID = dbo.VehicleMaster.ID
WHERE
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.PartyMasterID = ' + CAST(@partymasterid as nvarchar(50)) + '
GROUP BY
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.InventoryProductMasterID,
dbo.InventoryProductMaster.Name,
dbo.InventoryBiltyMaster.VehicleMasterID,
dbo.VehicleMaster.VehicleNumber
)
AS S
PIVOT
(
    MAX(BiltyCount)
    FOR [Name] IN (' + LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols)-1) + ')
)AS pvt';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
--now you can use ##temp
```

**Note**: use of global temp table can lead to unpredictable behavior if it gets updated from multiple sessions, you may think of giving a unique name for each session.

Comment: Thank you @PSK for the help.